# SQLAlchemy: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (many to many)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy is undoubtedly very powerful, but the documentation implicitly assumes lots of prior knowledge and on the subject of relationships, mixes between the `backref` and the newly-preferred `back_populates()` methods, which I find very confusing.

The following model design is pretty much an exact mirror of the guide in the documentation that deals with the [Association Objects for many-to-many relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects). You can see that the comments are still identical to those in the original article, and I've only changed the actual code.

```
class MatchTeams(db.Model):
    match_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('match.id'), primary_key=True)
    team_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('team.id'), primary_key=True)
    team_score = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable="True")

    # bidirectional attribute/collection of "user"/"user_keywords"
    match = db.relationship("Match",
                            backref=db.backref("match_teams",
                                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")
                            )
    # reference to the "Keyword" object
    team = db.relationship("Team")


class Match(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)

    # Many side of many to one with Round
    round_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('round.id'))
    round = db.relationship("Round", back_populates="matches")
    # Start of M2M

    # association proxy of "match_teams" collection
    # to "team" attribute
    teams = association_proxy('match_teams', 'team')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Match: %r>' % (self.id)


class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    goals_for = db.Column(db.Integer)
    goals_against = db.Column(db.Integer)
    wins = db.Column(db.Integer)
    losses = db.Column(db.Integer)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    matches_played = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Team %r with ID: %r>' % (self.name, self.id)
```

But this snippet, which is supposed to associate the team instance `find_liverpool` with the match instance `find_match` (both boilerplate objects), doesn't work:

```
find_liverpool = Team.query.filter(Team.id==1).first()
print(find_liverpool)
find_match = Match.query.filter(Match.id=="123").first()
print(find_match)

find_match.teams.append(find_liverpool)
```

And outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/REDACT/temp.py", line 12, in <module>
find_match.teams.append(find_liverpool)
File "/REDACT/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 609, in append
item = self._create(value)
File "/REDACT/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 532, in _create
 return self.creator(value)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given    
<Team 'Liverpool' with ID: 1>
<Match: '123'>
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information. What is producing that error? It can't be the snippet you've posted, because if the first line raised an error then `find_liverpool` wouldn't be populated, yet it clearly is. Please show the full code and traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the code I posted is what's producing the error. I added the full traceback. find_liverpool is being populated before the `TypeError` but for some reason the prints are output after it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The call to [`append`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#creation-of-new-values) is trying to [create a new instance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.association_proxy.params.creator) of `MatchTeams`, as can be seen from the documentation. This is also noted under "Simplifying Association Objects" that you linked to:

> Where above, each `.keywords.append()` operation is equivalent to:
>
> `>>> user.user_keywords.append(UserKeyword(Keyword('its_heavy')))`

Hence your

```
find_match.teams.append(find_liverpool)
```

is equivalent to

```
find_match.match_teams.append(MatchTeams(find_liverpool))
```

Since `MatchTeams` has no explicitly defined `__init__`, it's using the [`_default_constructor()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api._declarative_constructor) as [constructor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.constructor) (unless you've overridden it), which accepts only keyword arguments in addition to `self`, the only positional argument.

To remedy this either pass a [`creator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.association_proxy.params.creator) factory to your association proxy:

```
class Match(db.Model):

    teams = association_proxy('match_teams', 'team',
                              creator=lambda team: MatchTeams(team=team))
```

or define `__init__` on `MatchTeams` to suit your needs, for example:

```
class MatchTeams(db.Model):

    # Accepts as positional arguments as well
    def __init__(self, team=None, match=None):
        self.team = team
        self.match = match
```

or create the association object explicitly:

```
db.session.add(MatchTeams(match=find_match, team=find_liverpool))
# etc.
```